Cut off scatterplot markers in matplotlib after autoscale
I'm generating a simple image with a scatter and two dots and I want the dots to be fully visible, but ax.autoscale_view() seems not to work properly.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=150)
ax.scatter([0, 1], [0, 1], s=2000)
ax.autoscale_view()


Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the dots to be fully visible no matter the marker size s?

To adjust the axis so that the perimeter of points is inside of the plotting area, we need to:

Find the x and y extend of the perimeter of the dots in data-coordinate-space.
Adjust the margins accordingly to fit size of the points.

The size parameter s in ax.scatter sets the area of the bounding box (a square) of the marker (the dot) in units of points^2.  The marker also has a line drawn around it, controlled by the parameter linewidth. The default is 1.0.  To get the radius in points and the linewidth in points:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3), dpi=150)
c = ax.scatter([0, 1], [0, 1], s=2000)

r_face = sqrt(2000) / 2     # = 22.36 points
lw = c.get_linewidth()[0]   # = 1.0 points
r_points = r_face + lw      # = 23.36 points

To convert to pixel-coordinate-space, we need to convert from points to inches (72 points per inch), and then multiply by the DPI.
r_pixel = r_points / 72 * 150  # = 48.67 pixels

You can get the center of a point (we will use the point at 1, 1) and the boundary extent in pixel-coordinate-space using:
x_pixel, y_pixel = ax.transData.transform((1, 1))
bx_pixel = x_pixel + r_pixel
by_pixel = y_pixel + r_pixel

Because the dot radius is fixed in pixel-coordinate-space, it does not scale 1-to-1 with the data coordinates.  This makes a direct calculation difficult (I believe it is possible, I just don't know how).  We can iteratively adjust the margins and calculate whether the boundary is within the bounds of the data-coordinates.
bx_data, by_data = ax.transData.inverted().transform((bx_pixel, by_pixel))
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
while (bx_data > xmax) or (by_data > ymax):
    margin_x, margin_y = ax.margins()
    margin_x += 0.05
    margin_y += 0.05
    ax.margins(margin_x, margin_y)
    x_pixel, y_pixel = ax.transData.transform((1, 1))
    bx_pixel = x_pixel + r_pixel
    by_pixel = y_pixel + r_pixel
    bx_data, by_data = ax.transData.inverted().transform((bx_pixel, by_pixel))
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ax.autoscale()



This is beyond amazing, thank you a lot! In particular, I tried a lot of stuff but the linewidth was messing me up (why is it there by default?)

Probably for legacy reasons, although most graphics products have it turn on (think Microsoft Excel and PowerPoint drawing objects)

You can consider adding margins to your plot. Here's how you can do it:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=150)
ax.scatter([0, 1], [0, 1], s=1000)
ax.margins(0.15) # Adds 15% margin to both axes, you may need to adjust
ax.autoscale_view()

which generates:


Thanks for the answer! Seems like the manual way is the correct way to go

Try calling ax.margins() before ax.autoscale_view().
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=150)
ax.scatter([0, 1], [0, 1], s=2000)
ax.margins(x=0.25, y=0.25)
ax.autoscale_view()




Am I doing something wrong?

I don't thin so -- from the matplotlib docs it looks like autoscale_view() only scales based on the limits of the plotted data, not the size of the marker: "Autoscale the view limits using the data limits."

How can I get the dots to be fully visible no matter the marker size s?

I don't have a good solution for this one. I'd personally adjust the margins arguments by hand until you like the way it looks.
The units for marker size s are "points **2" which is in terms of distance on the screen. The margin units are in x,y coordinates. To get the dots to be fully visible, I think you would have to set the margins to whatever x and y coordinates are equivalent to the  radius of the dot which depends on the size of the graph in inches and the x and y limits of the plotted data. I don't think there's an easy way to do that conversion, but if you find one please post and prove me wrong.

Thanks for the answer I'll work on some conversion using figure dpi and other stuff to figure automatic margins out. I will post the answer when I find out!
